# How to resolve MS Project DateDiff Issue

Tags: vba, ms-project

I am in the middle of learning VBA for MS Project, and ma looking at variables.

Below is the course content and it works in the you tube demo for the teacher but for me I get a run time error argument is not valid.

The dates are in US formate and I am in Australia but I have changed this and doesnt seem to work

```
Sub UseVariables()
 
' minutes in an hour minPerHour = 60

' hours in a day hrsPerDay = 8

tskStart = "11/07/97 8:00 AM"

tskFinish = "18/07/97 5:00 PM"

'Date difference in minutes(counts only working days)

DateDiffInMin = Application.DateDifference(tskStart, tskFinish)



End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe you need to check/set the `Application.DateFormat`, and use the correct one for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.pjdateformat

Comment: Actually, what you want is the [DefaultDateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.defaultdateformat) *property* which returns or sets the date format in the application. The [DateFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.dateformat) *method* formats a date in the specified format.